# Change order of operation / deformation

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

Is there any way to change the order of mesh deformations from

basemesh->armature->shape key->final mesh

to

basemesh->shape key ->armature->final mesh

This would allow for shapekeys  to deform within the local space of bones. So useful for non-uniform volume preservation on facial rigs.

Any ideas on this? I thought it might be an idea to bake shape keys to vector displacement and pipe it into a displacement modifier which could be stacked after the armature modifier. Though this would be an annoying work around, especially working with multiple shape keys.